# What is an appropriate mapping for a field that is a title of a news article in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have a document for storing news articles' contents and metadata. How should I map field `title` which is a short text value of a news article title? I want to be able to search for the exact match (`keyword` type), but at the same time I want to apply some analyzer to it (`text` type).

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `title` field as `text` and use a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html)

I dont know what your requirements are for analyzer but you can use index template for your index and define the custom analyzer like below:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc_type": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, `match_phrase` query with the whole title worked fine on several examples but I do not know if it will always be the case.

Comment: It depends on the tokenizer you use. You can always test the analyzer to see how it indexes the title; refer the link i added for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use fields in your index mapping to store it as both text and keyword.

```
{
    "my-index": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use the analysed field, refer to "title". To use the keyword field, refer to "title.keyword".

Further reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to duplicate the field?, then you will have 2 fields one with `keyword` type and another with `text` type

Comment: That does not seem like a good solution. Imagine the overhead of managing those fields. CRUD operations must be in sync, searching could be an issue etc.

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html). It's not necessary copy all from backend. Now you can create the custom analyzer as you describe in your response but you must consider that the used tokenizer adds the complete article title in indexing and search time.

Comment: ok. `copy_to` may be a good option if you want to search against multiple fields. But not when you want to search on one field based on tokens.